# QML + QList<QObject*> not picked up in setContextProperty

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-quick, model-view

I'm attempting to do something akin to [Using C++ Models with Qt Quick Views](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html) . Specifically I want a `QList` of `QObject-derived instances` to render in a `QML ListView`.

If I follow the examples exactly, it works.

However, if I attempt to acquire the model through a custom Session object set to context, I run into issues.

Specifically, the session code looks like:

```
class Session : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    typedef QVariant result_type;

    Q_PROPERTY(result_type items READ items NOTIFY itemsChanged)
...
};
```

Each of its items is a `DataObject` which has a name property

Then effectively we do a:

```
ListView {
    model: session.items

    delegate: Rectangle {
        required property string name
    }
}
```

and in main:

```
Session session;

QQmlContext* context = engine.rootContext();
context->setContextProperty("session", &session);

...

QList<QObject*> dataList;
session.setItems(dataList);
```

Everything yields a:

```
Required property was not initialized
```

despite verifying there is content in `session.items`.  I use this kind of Session object for other QML things without incident.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

As mention in comments, one *can* get to properties via `modelData` which is a functional workaround, but the initial question remains.

I didn't put the QML in here because it's kinda big, but here's a gist of it in its current form https://gist.github.com/malachib/ac05c535fd11c5d4961feade307d9102

Comment: Does it work if you use a QVariantList instead of a QVariant?

Comment: It does not, identical results unfortunately

Comment: You cannot use QList. You're choices are QVariantList or QQmlListProperty. The reason for this is you need to create a collection whose memory management is compatible with the QML/JS engine. QVariantList is the least work. QQmlListProperty is better typed but you need to do more work to make it happen.

Comment: Also because they're QObject* pointers, you have to ask yourself who is responsible for the cleanup of the QObject*. For instance, can we make a reference to one of the elements and keep it after the list is gone? That could mean setObjectOwnership() needs to be called.

Comment: @StephenQuan `QVariantList` is literally an alias of `QList<QVariant>`.  Also, the example code uses `QList<QObject*>` directly to feed a `QVariant`, which is how I got my idea.   Lastly, I tried `QVariantList` and the results are identical, as mentioned already

Comment: The error is more pointing to the name property of your items. Have you tried to remove the required flag of your name property and check, if your model is basically there? Do you have a DataObject implementation you can show?

Comment: I am certain there is a `DataObject` in model[0].   I just discovered that `modelData.name` is present and functions as a workaround here - I can actually bind to it.  I'm still baffled why `name` isn't directly available in the delegate though as the docs indicate "As a convenience, the properties of the object are also made available directly in the delegate's context."

Answer (score 1):

As documentation says:

Required properties play a special role in model-view-delegate code: **If the delegate of a view has required properties whose names match with the role names of the view's model, then those properties will be initialized with the model's corresponding values.** For more information, visit the Models and Views in Qt Quick page.

So, if you have custom list in type of `QList<Object*>` where `QObject` is your object derived custom class here(instead of QAbstractItemModel derived one since the required values will be initalized as soon as they defined with the same name in the overridden rolenames function e.g. {"SomeRole", "someRole"} - required property string someRole), the defined required properties in the delegate will not be initialized with the default values of your `custom class` properties(also you can not directly set their values when defining them).

Comment: If this is the case, would the example provided [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html#qobjectlist-based-model) be in error since it does use required properties, but does not use a `QAbstractItemModel` ?

Comment: Nice touch. Provided example initialize initial properties with `QQuickView::setInitialProperties` method which is why it is working(also you need in your implementation), if it is commented you'll get the same error already.

Comment: Aha.  I hadn't considered that - I was thinking `setInitialProperties` only was concerned with setting `model` to a particular value.